# how do I apply xmlSerializer compatible attributes to return values in wcf

Tags: vb.net, wcf

How do I apply xmlserializer compatible attributes to return values (class) in wcf.
I have decorated my service contract with XmlSerializerFormat but wcf seems to ignore this.

```
Edit
```

This is a sample xml that I need to generate

```
    <account accAlias="0001000260920133" currency="USD">
        <availableBalance>380,072.00</availableBalance>
        <currentBalance>380,072.00</currentBalance>
    </account>
```

This is how I have implemented it in WCF

```
    Public Class account
        <XmlAttribute()> _
        Public accAlias As String
        <XmlAttribute()> _
        Public currency As String
        Public currentBalance As String
        Public availableBalance As String
    End Class
```

however the result im getting is this

```
    <account>
        <accAlias>0001000260920133</accAlias>
        <availableBalance>380,072.00</availableBalance>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <currentBalance>380,072.00</currentBalance>
    </account>
```

Comment: Be more specific, please. What do you mean by 'wcf seems to ignore this' and some code wouldn't hurt eighter

Comment: @MrPaulch See the edit above, hope that helps shed some light into what I need.

Comment: Just went through old responses, and here i see you having edited your post, and me not having reacted. So, I don't know whether you still need help in that regard.

Comment: @MrPaulch I haven't found a solution yet so any help will be much appreciated

Comment: OK, how do you actually serialize the Class? Do you implement IXmlSerializable? 
You might want to check that Interface out.
Also check what parameters XmlArgument takes, and parhaps try XmlIgnore()

Comment: im using XmlSerializerFormat

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about:

```
Public Class account
    <XmlAttribute("accAlias")>
    Public accAlias As String
    <XmlAttribute("currency")>
    Public currency As String
    <XmlElement("currentBalance")>
    Public currentBalance As String
    <XmlElement("availableBalance")>
    Public availableBalance As String
End Class
```

Comment: This didnt work either. We ended up using the values as XmlElements